# ReactJs + Redux ---> Try to call name of business where item.business_id === businessId

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, array.prototype.map

I would like to call the name of that business by equal it with idBusiness in this inquiry
I mean like this.

For information, that its first time I'm asked in here, so I don't know how to Bold some code too -_-
what I want to ask in this line

Link to={`/admin/business/${item.business_id}`}>**{businessId.business.filter(item => item._id === (item.business_id))}**

```
const allInquiries = useSelector(state => state.InquiryReducer);
const allBusiness = useSelector(state => state.BusinessReducer);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(GetAllInquiries());
  dispatch(GetAllBusiness()); }
```

my question in here

```
const unReadInquiries = () => {
if (allInquiries.allInquiries !== undefined) {
  return (
    allInquiries.allInquiries.docs.filter(item => item.isRead === false).map(item =>
      <Accordion>
        <Card className="mr-3 mb-3">
          <Card.Header className="bg-info">
            <Link to={`/admin/business/${item.business_id}`}**{businessId.business.filter(item => item._id === (item.business_id))}**</Link>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Body} eventKey={item._id}
            style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
            <img
              src={require('../assets/images/Screenshot from 2019-10-24 11-20-53.png')}
              alt="business-profile"
              width="30"
              height="30"
            />
            <span className="text-uppercase font-weight-bold ml-3">
              You have a new Inquiry from {item.name}
            </span>
            <Accordion.Collapse eventKey={item._id}>
              <Card
                className="mt-3" style={{cursor: 'auto'}}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <p>{item.description}</p>
                </Card.Body>
                <Card.Footer>
                  <Link to="#">
                    <Button>Read More</Button>
                  </Link>
                </Card.Footer>
              </Card>
            </Accordion.Collapse>
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    )
  )
}
```

}

thank you mastah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter method will return `array`. Use `find` instead of `filter`

```
<Link to={`/admin/business/${item.business_id}`}>
  {
    businessId.business.find(
      _item => _item._id === item.business_id
    )?.name
   // If you're using Babel Optional Chaining (?.) you
   // can access like this to prevent `undefined` error 
   // else, you have to do this
   //  businessId.business.find(
   //   _item => _item._id === item.business_id
   //  ) &&
   //  businessId.business.find(
   //   _item => _item._id === item.business_id
   //  ).name
  }
</Link>
```

Also you're declaring two `item` variables here. I have renamed the second one as `_item`.

Comment: thank you bro, it's worked, but how to call .name in there

Comment: name of which object you want to call?

Comment: _item (business name)

Comment: Just put `.name` after the braces. Let me update the answer